# What are the limits for UDK's landscape size?

Tags: udk

With the new (as of March 2011) [landscape tool](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/Landscape.html), the Unreal Development Kit supports bigger and (potentially) streaming landscapes than the old terrain tool. However, in my tests trying to import or create from scratch a small island (specifically, the island of [Tenerife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife) including some of the surrounding sea at 2m horizontal resolution, resulting in a roughly 35.000x20.000 pixel heightmap image - downright *tiny* in comparison to your usual GIS raster datasets), the UDK simply crashes. No error message or anything like that, simple program crash.

It seems as if I run against some kind of internal limit there, but without any clue as to where it happens and with the tool being rather new and undocumented, it's hard to say where those limits are.

Thus the question - what's the maximum size of a heightmap which can be used with the landscape tool in UDK, both in terms of the "amount of heightmap points" and the "width and height in [Unreal Units](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/UnrealUnits.html)"? In addition, if there are special tricks possible to break those limits (Streaming in the landscape? Portals?), some pointers would be nice ...

Answer (score 4):

From the page you linked :)

> Because of its powerful LOD system and the way it makes efficient use of memory, heightmaps up to 8192x8192 are now legitimately possible and feasible.

Comment: The same paragraph also says "The Landscape system paves the way for terrains that are orders of magnitude larger than what has been possible in Unreal Engine 3 previously." 8192 is just one order of magnitude larger than the previous max size of 513.

Comment: Possibility != Current limitation. Also, they may have just misused  the phrase "orders of magnitude". _(Asi jako u nas, kdyz neco udajne roste geometrickou radou ...)._

Comment: So basically, the way you read it is that Epic is planning to implement larger terrains sometime in the future based on the landscape tool, but for now (2011-10 release of the UDK) the size is limited to just 8192 to the side, right? I'll have to try out a few values for the heightmap along this boundary to verify what the toolset does then. I'm *very* sure however that it lets you enter values for the width and height which are both significantly bigger than that.

Comment: With good data streaming, there are no limitations.

Comment: @MartinSojka: Yes, maybe the landscape tool is just clumsy at dimension checking and lets the engine go wildfire.

Comment: @Tom: Right ... but you just can't rewrite the UDK streaming engine in UnrealScript nor using DLLBind.

Comment: It seems to be more complicated than that. I could successfully create a 9946x8416 landscape. On the other hand, 8192x8192 is *impossible* to use.